# Remove Middle Substring From a String in C#

Tags: c#

I am practicing C#

I want to remove middle Substring from a char array and add it in fornt

**Example 1**

> char array = " Fbh3dfbn8"

Substring 3 to 7 is removed and added at beginning:

> char array = "3dfFbhbn8"

**Example 2**

> char array = E5SS6SkGDE

Substring 4 to 7 is removed and added at beginning:

> char array= S6SkE5SGDE

Basically I want to divide the string into 3 parts where length of 1st and 3rd substring is same.

```
if (charArray.ToString().Length % 2 != 0 && charArray.ToString().Length >= 3)
{
    string subStringCharArray = charArray.ToString().Substring(charArray.ToString().Length / 2 - 1, 3);
    charArray.ToString().IndexOf(subStringCharArray);
    string changedString = subStringCharArray + charArray.ToString();

}
```

This is my code. At point string `subStringCharArray` inside `if` condition I always get `m.C as a output.But there is no`m.C` in my Char array.

Can any one help me or guide me to make this method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `new String(charArray)` in place of `charArray.ToString()`

```
Char[] charArray = new Char[]{'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

`charArray.ToString()` won't be the "abc" string. It will be 'System.Char[]' for any possible array.

Also

```
charArray.ToString().IndexOf(subStringCharArray);
```

won't change anything neither in array nor in string. It just returns the index of the substring - number. It does not modify anything.

You could try something like:

```
            Char[] charArray = new Char[] { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7' };
            String charArrayAsString = new String(charArray);

            String result = null;

            if (((charArrayAsString.Length % 2) != 0) &&
                 (charArrayAsString.Length >= 3))
            {
                Int32 middleBegins = charArrayAsString.Length / 2 - 1;
                Int32 middleLen = 3;

                result = charArrayAsString.Substring(middleBegins, middleLen) +
                    charArrayAsString.Substring(0, middleBegins) +
                    charArrayAsString.Substring(middleBegins + middleLen);                    
            }

            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide through 3:

```
string str1 = "Fbh3dfbn8";
int partLength = str1.Length / 3;
string result = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", 
    str1.Substring(partLength, str1.Length - (2 * partLength)),
    str1.Remove(partLength),
    str1.Substring(str1.Length - partLength));
```

If you insist on a `char[]`, it's easy enough to get a `string` from `char[]` via constructor or back to `char[]` via `string.ToCharArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string input = "E5SS6SkGDE";

char[] array = input.ToCharArray();

var result =
    array.Skip(3).Take(4)
        .Concat(array.Take(3))
        .Concat(array.Skip(7))
        .ToArray();

var output = new string(result);
```

The result I get is `S6SkE5SGDE`.